# Inserting into a relational structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, insert, relational-database

We're supposed to create relational databases, not flat structures. You create tables with relationships to other tables. You normalize to remove duplication, and de-normalize to improve performance. This all makes sense. But, I'm having trouble finding a good mechanism to insert into a relational structure. Are there no good mechanism for inserting records into a relational structure. Is there something like:

`INSERT INTO x LEFT JOIN y ON x.id = y.id VALUES(...)?`

The best I could come up with is a stored proc that does:

```
INSERT INTO x
SELECT id FROM x (or @@id)
INSERT INTO y
```

This seems counter to the whole relational model...

It's the insert equivalent of not having joins. Would we put up with having to do multiple selects and join the results together ourselves?

Comment: If you want to insert into multiple tables, use multiple SQL statements (i.e., batch statements), stored procs, or triggers. I am not sure what you mean by *no good mechanism*.

Comment: Well, if you use Java, for example JPA implementations like Eclipselink do this for you.

Comment: To expand on @RedFilter's comment, you can wrap multiple operations, e.g. INSERTs, in a single transaction to ensure that the logical operation is atomic.  Your second example is a perfect case.  Note that failed operations may still leave traces, for example if your second INSERT failed and a transaction rolled back the first INSERT there would still be an identity value consumed.

Comment: @RedFilter in my opinion this is somewhat like saying you don't need joins, you can just do multiple selects and join them together your self. It seems odd to me that sql would give you joins, but not the same operation for inserts.

Comment: The ANSI standard (2008) apparently allows for insertion to views, when it 'makes sense' (ie, probably not for something that contains aggregations), but it's optional, and not all vendors have implemented it (DB2 I know hasn't - but you can define 'instead-of' triggers).  What else would you recommend?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I wish this wasn't optional. What I would really like (and was hoping something existed) was the ability to insert into views and joins. When it makes sense would definitely be a clause.

Comment: [Looks like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx?ppud=4) SQL Server 2008 supports what DB2 does - views referencing single tables (or a selection of columns referencing a single table) can be updated directly, otherwise, use an 'instead-of' trigger.  Can't speak to different versions, though.

Comment: @OP I think you just need to stop thinking of data like objects.  Relational data doesn't work that way.  Relational data means independent rows of data that can be related to other rows in the same or another table via a key; a highly flexible relationship that doesn't always fit neatly into XML-like hierarchies.  Also keep in mind that SQL was designed for querying; the tools for inserting data are there, but it is not the primary function of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You normalize to remove duplication, and de-normalize to improve
>   performance.

You normalize to remove certain kinds of update anomalies. You denormalize to improve SELECT performance, usually at the expense of update performance and update anomalies.

The relational model itself not only supports updatable views, it *requires* updatable views. But as far as I know, this is still a research area; the technical problems are significant, particularly when you have to support updates to views in the most general cases.

Current SQL products offer limited support at best. (And SQL is still pretty far from relational.)  Over the years, I think we've all come to expect to have to write triggers if we want updatable views.

At some point, whether you do this in application code, triggers, or stored procedures, you're going to find yourself stuck with multiple INSERT statements wrapped in a transaction.